# Conversion of Undirected graph to a Directed Graph with a Constraint

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given an undirected graph and a node, how would you modify the graph into a directed graph such that, any path leads to one particular node.The question is coming up as a popular algorithmic question in SE interviews

Answer (score 1):

This is simply creating a tree rooted at (and directed to) the given node and then completing it to a DAG, any search algorithm (e.g. BFS or DFS) can give you a solution:
Starting with the given node, using the search algorithm - Whenever encountering a node, connect it to an already connected node (usually to the one from which you got to it), you can then set the direction for the remaining edges according to the order in which you encountered the nodes (from the latter to the earlier)